# What are the typical use cases of MeteorJS? What are the essentials missing in Meteor.JS before it can be adopted into mainstream development?

Tags: meteor

Brief relevance of the question.

I am working on a project, which is my first tech start up. I found the framework very fascinating, but i am afraid that it would lead to troubles because of certain drawbacks that are not meeting my eye at the moment. I would appreciate the Stackoverflow community's perspective on it.

The Project i am planning will be function as a Question & Answer forum much like Quora or Stackoverflow for certain domain of professionals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meteor is appropriate for almost anything - that part of your question is a bit broad, but I refer you to the [Meteor Trello roadmap](https://trello.com/board/meteor-roadmap/508721606e02bb9d570016ae) for features that still need to be developed.

That said, I think that if you can develop anything using Rails/PHP/whatever, you can make it in Meteor and in 1/10 the time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you also compare Meteor with NodeJS? Which will be better in your reckoning?

Comment: It's like comparing NodeJS to Javascript. Node is a low-level system that allows Javascript to run standalone as an application, for example as a web server. Meteor is a framework for building dynamic web applications that run on top of node. When creating Meteor application, you use Node underneath, and frequently you'll be using Node commands and libraries – in the same manner as you use Javascript when using Node.js.

Comment: brilliant. So what kind of problems should i anticipate if i'm building an application like quora on meteor? I have looked at the trello roadmap, i'm not anticipating huge spike in traffic (realistically) any other issues apart from scale?